# Add two items at a time to struct in for loop

Tags: go

I'm trying to add 2 items at once to a struct array, then continuously every 2 items create a new struct array and append to the final `Container` struct. I'm struggling to find the proper way of doing this.

To further illustrate what I mean:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Container struct {
    Collection []SubContainer
}

type SubContainer struct {
    Key   string
    Value int
}

func main() {
    commits := map[string]int{
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3,
        "d": 4,
        "e": 5,
        "f": 6,
    }

    sc := []SubContainer{}
    c := Container{}

    for k, v := range commits {
        sc = append(sc, SubContainer{Key: k, Value: v})
    }

    for _, s := range sc {
        c.Collection = append(c.Collection, s)
    }

    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

Link: https://play.golang.org/p/OhSntFT7Hp

My desired behaviour is to loop through all the `commits`, and every time the `SubContainer` reaches len(2), append to the `Container`, and create a new `SubContainer` until the for loop is complete. If there's an uneven number of elements, then the last SubContainer would just hold one element and append to Container like normal.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? Apologies if this is a obvious answer, very new to Go!

Comment: What's the purpose of `sc`? You can just directly append to `c.Collection` and skip `sc` completely. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "reset" a slice by setting it to nil. Also, you may not be aware that nil-slices work just fine with append:

```
var sc []SubContainer
c := Container{}

for k, v := range commits {
    sc = append(sc, SubContainer{Key: k, Value: v})
    if len(sc) == 2 {
        c.Collection = append(c.Collection, sc...)
        sc = nil
    }
}
if len(sc) > 0 {
    c.Collection = append(c.Collection, sc...)

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ecj52fkwpO

Comment: Out of curiosity, while this is appending two at a time. The end result of `Container` still seems to be single slice values. Is there a trick to get the Container struct to be able to hold multiple `SubContainer`s? For example, so you could iterate through c.Collection and see the groupings

Comment: I was wondering why you wanted to append them two at a time. If you want a list of pairs you need to declare Collection as a slice of slices. https://play.golang.org/p/pckuuomKsj